# Eliminar registro en API con axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, axios

Estoy intentando eliminar un registro en la base de datos usando `axios` en `vue.js`. La petición se realiza a una `API` en `Laravel8`.

El método que uso en `axios`:

```
eliminarCoche: function (id_car) {
  axios
    .delete("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/car/eliminar/" +id_car})
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

La ruta en el archivo api de `Laravel`:

```
Route::delete('/car/eliminar/{id}', [CarController::class, 'destroy']);
```

El controlador usado para eliminar el registro:

```
public function destroy(Car $car)
{
    $car->delete();
}
```

Al llamar a la función `eliminarCoche`, no se elimina el registro en la BBDD.

¿Alguien me puede indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: A simple vista estas llamando a `/api/car/eliminar/` y la ruta la tienes como `/car/eliminar/`. Por otra parte, podrías indicar con es el problema exactamente por favor?

Comment: @MitaCloud Por propia experiencia se que se usa el 'api' en las rutas con axios. El problema es que no se elimina el registro en la base de datos al llamar a la funcion 'eliminarCoche'

Comment: si alcanzas a ver el request con un die a dump (dd) ?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ He cambiado el $car por $id y ha funcionado, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema, era la variable que recibe el controlador encargado de eliminar el registro de la base de datos. Para arreglar esto solo hace falta cambiar el nombre de la variable que se encuentra junto en el controlador para que concuerde con la variable recibida en la ruta:

```
public function destroy(Car $id)
{
    $id->delete();
}
```

Ref: Laravel Routing [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)